# Anti-derivative of constant to a power

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I approach a problem like this?

$\int xe^{x^2 - 1} dx$?

I tried U-substitution, but what confuses me is that $x$ is not the first derivative of $x^2 - 1$

$\frac{du}{dx} x^2 - 1 = 2x$

$du = 2x \space dx$

But I don't understand how this will help me at all

Comment: That means the factor $ \ x \ dx \ $ in your integral can be replaced by $ \ \frac{1}{2} du \ $ .  Your integral becomes $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \int \ e^u \ \ du \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int xe^{x^2 - 1} dx=\frac 1 2\int2xe^{x^2-1}dx$, now what is the derivative of $e^{x^2-1}$?

Comment: thanks... That solved it or me

Answer (score 1):

For $\large \int xe^{x^2-1}dx$, note that $\large x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)$, so that $$ \int xe^{x^2-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)e^{f(x)}dx$$
where $\large f(x)=x^2-1$.

Can you think what $\large\int\left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)e^{f(x)}dx$ simplifies to?

Answer (score 0):

what's the point of setting u equal to anything for an integral this simple. Just multiply by one.
$$\int xe^{x^2-1}dx = \int xe^{x^2-1}dx\frac{\frac{d(x^2-1)}{dx}}{\frac{d(x^2-1)}{dx}} = \int xe^{x^2-1}\frac{d(x^2-1)}{2x} = \int e^{x^2-1}\frac{d(x^2-1)}{2} = \int \frac{1}{2}e^{x^2-1}d(x^2-1) = \frac{1}{2}e^{x^2-1} + C$$